# Processing BigCommece SignedPayload however its null

Tags: bigcommerce

Im building an integration with big commerce. I have setup the oauth integration and connected with my application.

Part of the documentation describes a `pay_load` token is sent with requests. For me it doesnt when my application first registers. 
[About the load request and response](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/load#load)

If I reload the page (my bigcommerce page) the parameter is then passed as expected to my application.

Has anyone experienced this? Im not sure if its a bug with my code or BC....I assume its mine...but I dont know where to look

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug. This is currently intended as most app installing workflows.

When you first install an app, the Auth Callback is sent allowing the 3rd party (or you) to respond with a UI to feed into the control panel. The Load Callback is not needed during the initial install process because the 3rd party (or you) has a way to give us content to display - which is really the point of the Load Callback.

Ideally, you build your Auth Callback to give the same UI interface back as the Load Callback then you're done.